# A third column to accumulate values over 3 mins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm practicing SQL and I would like to add a column to do accumulate values over 3 minutes:

```
Time Data Cumulative
8:00 1    1
8:01 2    3
8:02 3    6
8:03 2    7
8:04 1    6
8:04 1    4
```

I wrote this SQL so far :

```
SELECT EX.E3TimeStamp,EX.Data,EX.Data AS Sum 
FROM EX 
ORDER BY EX.E3TimeStamp ASC
```

But I have difficult to find solution. I tried with GROUP BY and DATEDIFF but it was unsuccessful (error).

Please if you can give me some tips !

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: pls. tag the DBMS  (MySQL, MS SQL Server, etc....) which u r using.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft using SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

One generic method uses a correlated subquery.  The functions for dealing with times vary by database, but the idea is:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(t2.data)
        from t t2
        where t2.time >= t.time - interval '3 minute' and
              t2.time <= t.time
       ) as cumulative
from t;
```

Note:  This uses ANSI standard `interval` syntax for the time calculation.  This may vary by database.

EDIT:

The SQL Server version is:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(t2.data)
        from t t2
        where t2.time >= dateadd(minute, -3, t.time) and
              t2.time <= t.time
       ) as cumulative
from t;
```

Comment: I think the interval doesn't work in my case. Also I have a question about t2 ? is it a copy of t ? In my case, I just need to create by query a new column 'sum' where I can do the sum over the last 3 minutes.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server, which I think has basic functions only.

[screenshot of my table][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/udfB4.png

Comment: Thanks for you help to translate the query to SQL Server. I still have a question about t2 is the query. It is copy of t ? It is created automatically by the server from the query ? I still have some difficulty with the mechanics.

Comment: `t2` is a table alias.  It is a second reference to `t`.